# Simulate one monitor from two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I want to combine two monitors into one simulated one, so I can record or share both monitors at once by recording the simulated one. How can I simulate a monitor in that way? (I couldn't find any solutions online.)

Comment: If I am not mistaken Xorg allways considers the screens to be one. Anyway, you can record both screens with e.g. Kazam.

Comment: One problem with that is that some programs don't allow me to do that.